# Insertar un registro de tabla relacionadas desde c# a sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Necesito ayuda! estoy trabajando con herencia. Cliente:Persona.
y necesito insertar desde la clase Cliente, donde están los métodos (registrar, modificar, eliminar, listar).
Necesito que se inserte en un método!
la idea que tengo es identificar el id de la persona para insertar el cliente, e identificar el tipo cliente.

```
public void Registrar()
    {
        string sql = string.Format("Insert into Persona (Nombre, ApPaterno,                ApMaterno, FechaNac, Documento, Direccion, Telefono, Sexo, Email) 
 values('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}')",      this.Nombre, this.ApPaterno, this.ApMaterno, this.FechaNac, this.Documento,   this.Direccion, this.Telefono, this.Sexo, this.Email);
        //("Insert into Cliente(Id, codigo, TipoCliente) values({0})",   this.ID, this.codigo, this.TipoCliente)

        Conexion.EjecutarComando(sql);
    }
```

Mi base de datos es la siguiente:

```
create table Persona(
Id int not null identity(1,1),
Nombre varchar(50) not null,
ApPaterno varchar(50),
ApMaterno varchar(50),
FechaNac date not null,
Documento varchar(20) not null,
Direccion varchar(50),
Telefono varchar(20),
Sexo varchar(20) not null,
Email varchar(50),
constraint pk_persona primary key(Id),
)

create table TipoCliente(
Id int identity(1,1) not null,
Nombre varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_TipoCliente primary key(Id),
)

create table Cliente(
Id int not null,
codigo int not null,
TipoCliente int not null,
constraint pk_cliente primary key(Id),
constraint fk_persona_Cliente foreign key(Id)
references Persona(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
constraint fk_Cliente_TipoCliente foreign key(TipoCliente)
references TipoCliente(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

Comment: lo que tendrías que hacer es un método en la clase persona que inserte y te retorne el Id_persona. >Y luego con ese dato insertar el cliente

Comment: Trata de organizar mejor tu código, cuesta un poco de trabajo comprenderlo.

Comment: una consulta... esa misma operacion para Mysql, como se puede hacer pls... gracias

Answer (score 7):

Lo primero que aconsejaria es que uses parametros, unir en un string los valores del `insert` no es recomendable

El codigo deberia lucir de esta forma

```
public void Registrar()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 

    string sql = @"Insert into Persona (Nombre, ApPaterno, ApMaterno, 
                    FechaNac, Documento, Direccion, Telefono, Sexo, Email) 
                values(@nombre, @ApPaterno, @ApMaterno, ...)"; 

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", this.Nombre); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApPaterno", this.ApPaterno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApMaterno", this.ApMaterno);
        .
        .

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```

usa **SIEMPRE** parametros para asignar los valores.

Por el problema en la herencia analiza este articulo

[n-Layer - SchoolManager - Herencia y navegación de entidades relacionadas (1/2)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2013/03/n-layer-schoolmanager-herencia-y.html)

Veras como defino un ejemplo usando `Instructor` que hereda de `Persona` entonces desde el metodo Save() se llama primero al grabar de la clase base (o sea persona) se inserta y luego se prosigue con el instructor. Al insertar la persona obtienes el Id para poder relacionar los registros entre las tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una estructura de datos donde una tabla depende de la otra, como es tu caso

> Persona --> Cliente

Para ello lo que debes hacer primero es insertar el registro en la tabla **padre**, en este caso Persona, y luego con el Id generado insertar el registro en la tabla **hijo**, que vendria a ser el Cliente. Ese debería ser el orden para que la referencia de Llave Foranea funcione y no se produzca un error.
En la respuesta anterior te muestra como hacer el insert con uso de parametros, tendrias que hacer un registrar para Persona y uno para Cliente.